# Get highest highscore entries between given dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a `scores_score` table which contains following columns:

```
id, player_name, value, created_at
```

I have to fetch N (100) best scores where:

1. player_name must be unique across results
2. only best score for given player_name should be returned
3. results have to be filtered by date range

Lets say I have following data:

```
id      player_name    value          date
1       A               400        2016-09-10
2       B               200        2016-09-12
3       C               400        2016-09-15
4       C               500        2016-09-14
5       B               100        2016-09-20
6       A               6000       2015-01-01
7       B               1200       2016-09-29
```

And want to get best players with their scores between 2016-09-01 and 2016-09-20. I should get the:

```
id      player_name    value          date
4       C               500        2016-09-14
1       A               400        2016-09-10
2       B               200        2016-09-12
```

This is my approach to solve it, but there is an issue in nested SELECT as it fetches the best score of the player overall not within date ranges.

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM (SELECT player_name, max(value) AS max_value
      FROM scores_score
      GROUP BY player_name
      ORDER BY max(value) DESC) a
INNER JOIN scores_score b ON a.player_name = b.player_name AND a.max_value = b.value
WHERE CAST(b.created_at AS DATE) >= %(date_border)s
ORDER BY b.value DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: What prevents you of adding a where clause on the subquery?

Comment: I've been thinking about adding `WHERE CAST(b.created_at AS DATE) >= %(date_border)s` to the subquery, but after that I'll need to add the `created_at` to the GROUP BY which breaks everything up (I don't have best score per player name no more).

Comment: Why was this question voted down? He put in very clearly his data and expected results and what he has tried. How else is one to ask a question?

Comment: Why would you have to add the `created_at` to the GROUP BY? You do not have to add columns used on WHERE clauses to the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (player_name) *
    from scores_score
    where date between '2016-09-01' and '2016-09-20'
    order by player_name, value desc
) s
order by value desc
limit 100
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to work and will provide you with expected output. Use `row_number()` window function to mark highest score for each player between dates (`rn = 1`) and then order the result set by `value` descending and finally limit the output to 100 highest.

```
select 
  id, player_name, value, created_at
from (
  select
    id, player_name, value, created_at,
    row_number() over (partition by player_name order by value desc, id) as rn
  from scores_score
  where created_at between '2016-09-01' and '2016-09-20'
  ) ranks
where rn = 1
order by value desc
limit 100
```

Note that additional column `id` for sorting within `row_number` function is to resolve ties (even though it assigns only one value per row within partition) that would involve the same player having two rows with equal values that are within given date. This would get older record and if they differ with `created_at` date you would see a difference in the output :-)

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little cumbersome but should work. First select just the players and values within your date range (a). Then select the max score by player (b). Then join the id and date (c):

```
SELECT c.id, c.player_name, c.value, c.date
FROM
scores_score c
INNER JOIN
(SELECT player_name, max(value)
FROM
(SELECT player_name, value
FROM scores_score
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-20') a
GROUP BY player_name) b
ON c.player_name = b.player_name
AND c.value = b.value
ORDER BY value
LIMIT 100
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10db42/6